Meaning of 亂 in 幾可亂真?
幾可亂真 means something along the lines of "near identical to the real thing".
幾 = 幾乎 almost
可 = 可以 be/like
亂真 = near identical to the real object
Correct me if some of my understanding above is wrong. My question is what does 亂 mean? In
亂真 it seems 亂 is an adjective describing 真, so I can postulate 亂 means strongly/very. But the word 亂 itself means a mess/disorder, so I'm confused as to what it really means in 亂真. Thanks for the help.

几可乱真:
几:几乎 almost
可:可以 can
乱:错乱，混淆: mix up, confuse
真:真实: real, genuine
所以这个词的意思就是几乎可以跟真的媲美（但还是假的）
Therefore, the meaning of this phrase is: one could almost compare this (article, thing) to the genuine article (but it is still not genuine)

几(幾)可乱(亂)真 could be transformed into 几可使真乱.
乱真 -> 使真乱
In ancient Chinese literature, it was a very common way of using an adjective as a verb to express that subject made object become like what the adjective described which was called 使动用法, there are some other examples:

故天将降大任于斯人也，必先苦其心志，劳其筋骨，饿其体肤，空乏其身，行拂乱其所为，所以动心忍性，曾益其所不能；
阙秦以利晋,唯君图之。

You may find that there were also some verbs and nouns bold in the sentences, what means you can also use 使动用法 with a noun or a verb :
Examples of nouns:

故扁鹊不能肉白骨，微、箕不能存亡国（使白骨肉）；
祸国殃民（使国祸，使民殃）；
文王以百里之壤而臣诸侯（使诸侯臣）。

Examples of verbs:

既来之，则安之；（使之安）
君子正其衣冠，尊其瞻视，俨然人望而畏之，斯不亦威而不猛乎？（使其衣冠正，使其瞻视尊）。

使动用法 was used to make the subject become something(by using nouns) or execute the behavior(by using verbs) or look like the adjectives described.
Hope the answer could help you in the future.

亂(v) = 冒充 (impersonate; imitate); 使混亂 (make confuse)
以假亂真  = Impersonate the real person with a fake; imitate the real thing with a fake
幾可亂真 = Can almost confuse (passing off) as the real thing
